# Android Quickblox 1.2 runtime issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime, quickblox

I have a nasty runtime issue.

Using Eclipse and latest Android SDK (22.6.3).  Code compiles, but at runtime, it fails to find the interface.  See log below:

05-02 16:48:36.535: I/dalvikvm(20471): Failed resolving
Lcom/ss/core/Chat/Core/RoomChat; interface 2842
'Lcom/quickblox/module/chat/listeners/RoomListener;'

05-02 16:48:36.535: W/dalvikvm(20471): Link of class
'Lcom/ss/core/Chat/Core/RoomChat;' failed

YES, I did add the Quickblox SDK file to the /libs folder.

Yes, I have ALSO tried to add it as an external JAR *AND* added it to the Build Path's "Order and Export" tab.

I also tried manually modifying the build path by right clicking on the jar in the libs/ folder and ->Build Path->Add to build path ... and then ensuring it was exported.

Same result all 3 times.

I also created a support ticket, but got the standard response of "add you your Build path", despite me saying that it was already done in the support ticket.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems while importing quickblox samples into Eclipse. But I fixed them adding jar to build path and exporting it. I read this article: http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample
 Using latest samples I had problems while compiling samples cause I had to add app-compat project in dependency and support-v4 lib in build path. I fixed it successfully but in not all samples. Today I am using Mac Os. When I used Eclipse on Windows I had more problems. What OS are you using ? What Eclipse's version are you using?